# Web Analytic Configuration

Tags: web-analytics

How can I make Web Analytic work? I can't find any official site that explains how I can do it, which services I should configure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266382%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for 2010, Since web analytics is [discontinued](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2013-HA102892827.aspx) for 2013, you will probably not find any new documentation from Microsoft for 2013.

Comment: So should I use Google Analytic? I get the script from Google Analytic for the web site but I couldn't find any article about it. There is only articles for Office 365. I couldn't find any of it for SP server.

Comment: Depends, the Search has taken over some of the work that Web Analytics did before, see this: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/new-sharepoint-2013-analytics